# How do you select specific records for each sub record?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Forgive me if im having trouble explaining this. But basically I have:

```
 
|Place| Agreement  | Open Date      | Closed Date | FlagDate
| 1   | a          | 1/29/2011      | 7/29/2011   | 2/29/2011
| 1   | b          | 2/15/2016      | 7/30/2016   | 2/29/2011
| 1   | c          | 3/29/2015      | 8/02/2015   | 2/29/2011
| 2   | d          | 4/29/2011      | 7/28/2011   | 6/29/2012
| 2   | e          | 5/29/2012      | 7/30/2012   | 6/29/2012
| 3   | f          | 6/29/2011      | 8/01/2011   | 7/15/2011
| 3   | g          | 7/29/2012      | 8/02/2012   | 7/15/2011
```

Where there can be multiple Agreements for a single Place. The FlagDate will be the same for each individual Place (ie all of Place 1 has a FlagDate of 2/29/2011)

What I would like to do is simply select the Agreement where the FlagDate falls in between the Open and Close date (the open and close date will never overlap with different agreements.) So the output for the above would be

```
|Place| Agreement  | Open Date      | Closed Date | FlagDate
| 1   | a          | 1/29/2011      | 7/29/2011   | 2/29/2011
| 2   | e          | 5/29/2012      | 7/30/2012   | 6/29/2012
| 3   | f          | 6/29/2011      | 8/01/2011   | 7/15/2011
```

Comment: On a sidenote: Looks like a bad data design to me. If it's one flagdate per place, there should be a place table with one record per place that contains the flag date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the BETWEEN operator in your WHERE clause to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE flagdate BETWEEN opendate AND closeddate;
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it worked fine. I was under the impression initially that it wouldnt work correctly, as I thought you would need to somehow specify that, for each distinct Place, you would want to find the flagdate that is between.

Im still a little confused as to "why" it works, however. When a query runs, is it running the statements on each record?

Comment: The WHERE clause is applied to each record, yes. That's just how it works. So you don't have to worry about "For each `place`" because you stated that a flagdate will only occur within on of the records start/ends. If that was a concern then you would have to get more creative with the sql. For future reference the `sub records` (records for each distinct place) is called a "Window" and there are "window functions" that will operate within just a single window. Such as `COUNT(flagdate) OVER (PARTITION BY place) as count_of_similar_places`. Which you could stick in your SELECT clause.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about windows and window functions, thats exactly what I was looking for